# How to format new HDD at first time?

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

Someone told me i can format my new 1.5Tb HDD with quickformat. I can't believe this but i can't find infos about this issue.

What's the best option when formatting totally new hard drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quick format.

The full format is the same as quick format but it also checks for bad sectors on the disk and on big volumes can take a long time. Really long. I made a wrong choice when formatting 300 GB disk and full format took around 1h as I recall.

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302686

Comment: Thank you, it's clear now. The provided link is useful too.